# Correlation among features (e.g. doc length, punctuation, ... ) in classifying spam emails

Tags: python, classification, text-mining, correlation

I extracted some other features from my dataset regarding punctuation, capital letters, upper case words. I got these value:

[image]

looking at the correlation with my target variable (1=spam, 0=not spam), using .corr() in python.
BT stands for binary text, e.g., and BS stands for binary summary, where I assign 1 or 0 based on the presence of a capital letter in the text/summary, or upper case word, or...

Do you think that features like these can be useful in model building? I cannot see very strong correlations, but I would like to determine if an email can be spam or not based also on features like these (number of character/text length; presence of !, upper case words,....).

I have around 1000 emails, but only 50 are spam (maybe too small to extract useful information).
However, I had to extract these information, so it is a new dataset, built on my own, so I could not get many more spam emails (and I would like to not use datasets from kaggle, for instance).

What do you think?

Comment: Pandas .corr() can’t be used for binary vectors because does use pearson, spearman and kendal that all of this methods are not suited for binary vectors ... you need to build a custom function to calculate a meaningful correlation coefficient like Phi coefficient.

Comment: ... so corr coefficient matrix you got is not informative. Try a Lasso model and see if this will select this features for the model and check confusion matrix if does capture minority class. Use weight with a balance ration for your dataset and should work.

Comment: thank you @n1tk. I will review it, trying to apply more meaningful correlations. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First about the features i  think you could add some such as :

- the time when the letter is received,
- number of links in the email,
- the whole structure (does it follow typical structure for email),
- number of words that contains numbers in it,
- what is the whole mood of the email (sales,threats,info,...-for this purpose you can use sentiment analysis),
- number of attachments ,
- type of attachments and so on.

After that try with feature selection (you could read more about it [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://towardsdatascience.com/the-5-feature-selection-algorithms-every-data-scientist-need-to-know-3a6b566efd2&ved=2ahUKEwj4sN2l577sAhWC-yoKHRLOCigQjjgwEXoECCwQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1Rz2Js1ZfGDNqEWZ8c0z-3)). For the imbalance data you need to resample the data. I would:

- add copies of spam emails(oversampling)
- try to generate new spam email (smote)

You can read more [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://towardsdatascience.com/methods-for-dealing-with-imbalanced-data-5b761be45a18&ved=2ahUKEwiS7tHG5r7sAhU0A2MBHbRvATIQjjgwHnoECCsQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2Y74imyAXPHEQpMezoOPKE).
I hope my answer will give you some clarity.

Comment: Thank you so much @mariq vlahova (and Erwan for editing her answer)

Comment: Thanks Erwan for editing my comment 